# SAPUI5 hybrid app - How to prevent multiple logins on different platforms

Tags: authentication, hybrid-mobile-app, sap-web-ide, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-mobile-services

We have developed a hybrid mobile application in SAP Cloud Platform connected with the SAP Mobile Services. If a user is logged using a device and the same user tries to log-in the application via web, he should not be able to log-in (I.e. prevent multi logon).

Is there any configuration I'm missing out?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, I missed the reply - if you want to prevent users from concurrently logging in from multiple locations, I believe you will need to look into your Identity Provider (IdP) settings. Mobile Services does not handle authorization itself but delegates to whatever is configured as the Cloud Platform account IdP, and therefore there is nothing much you can do from the app/backend/Mobile Services. The same applies to other cloud services as well.

Alternatively, and I guess that is *not* what you are doing, if you are using some backend-based login (e.g. plain old user table), you could maintain a flag tracking sessions for the user, and then add some backend logic to prevent multi-logins from happening.